# Constructing node with non-standard types

Tags: python, yaml

I am trying to work out if I can import a yaml file and use my own object types for mappings and sequences

In the standard constructors, it uses built in types for these:
http://pyyaml.org/browser/pyyaml/tags/3.10/lib/yaml/constructor.py#L112
http://pyyaml.org/browser/pyyaml/tags/3.10/lib/yaml/constructor.py#L120

I was wondering if there is a way to have these constructed with my own data types for mapping and sequences without me monkey patching yaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.construct_*

I have tried the following:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from noconflict import classmaker
from yaml import YAMLObject
import yaml

try:
    # Try for python 3 first
    from collections.abc import Sequence
    from collections.abc import Mapping
except ImportError:
    from collections import Sequence
    from collections import Mapping


class SettingsMapping(Mapping, YAMLObject):
    __metaclass__ = classmaker()
    yaml_tag = '!!map'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getitem__(self, item, default=None):
        return self.__dict__.get(item, default=default)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.__dict__.iterkeys()

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.__dict__)


class SettingsSequence(Sequence, YAMLObject):
    __metaclass__ = classmaker()
    yaml_tag = '!!seq'

    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.list = args

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.list[item]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.list)

for cls in [SettingsMapping, SettingsSequence]:
    yaml.add_constructor(cls.yaml_tag, cls)

y = yaml.load(open('input.yaml')
```

where noconflict.classmaker is from:
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/204197-solving-the-metaclass-conflict/

but:

```
>>> type(y)
dict
```

Comment: Have you looked at [subclassing YAMLObject](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#Constructorsrepresentersresolvers)?

Comment: Edited the original post with something I tired.

Comment: Well you'd need to use other tags for your classes, obviously. If you actually want to change what PyYAML uses for `!!seq` and `!!map`, I am pretty sure you need to modify its source.

Comment: That is what I am trying to achieve, I would like to not have to modify my yaml files to use my version of mapping and sequence